# Prepend components in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager

The `.add` method appends components to the end of another component. I'm trying to prepend a component to the beginning of another component. How would I accomplish that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you could use the [add(Component, int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component,%20int%29) method, where the `int` specifies the insertion position.  An insertion position of zero should do the trick to prepend a component.

---

(I don't know if this is the right approach though.  Maybe a layout manager would be better.)

Comment: Pardon me for the edit, added the latest Java 7 link, instead for the former version. +1 for the answer, as I guess this can be done with this method.  Another workaround I can think of is changing the `Component's Orientation` of the said container and then using `BoxLayout/Anyother Layout(never tried it though)` :-).

Answer (score 4):

`Component` has an [add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component,%20int%29) method that takes two params - the object to be added and the index for it to be inserted at.  With that in mind, you can attempt to prepend you component by doing the following:

```
 comp.add(newPanel, 0);
 comp.validate();
```

Comment: Pardon me for the edit, added the latest Java 7 link, instead for the former version. +1 for the answer, as I guess this can be done with this method.  Another workaround I can think of is changing the `Component's Orientation` of the said container and then using `BoxLayout/Anyother Layout(never tried it though)` :-).

Answer (score 3):

You should use a [*layout manager*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) to accomplish that. The standard layout manager, which is the one with which every container starts by default, just adds items at the end.

Something like this, for example, would do the trick:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
panel.add(lowComponent,BorderLayout.CENTER);
panel.add(highComponent,BorderLayout.NORTH);
```